# $\overline{A}=\overline{B}$ implies $\partial A=\partial B ?$

Tags: general-topology

Let $A,B$ be two **non-empty** subsets of $\mathbb{C}$.

> Assume that $\overline{A}=\overline{B}$. Is 
>   $$\partial A=\partial B ?$$
>   Here $\overline{A}$ and $\overline{B}$ denote respectively the closure of $A$ and $B$. Also $\partial A$ and $\partial B$ denote respectively the bondary of $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Take $A=[-1,1]$ and $B=[-1,0) \cup (0,1]$. Now $\overline{B}=\overline{A}=A=[-1,1]$, but $\partial A=\{-1,1\}$ and $\partial B=\{-1,0,1\}$

Comment: Under which conditions the assertion holds? Thanks.

Comment: @Schüler under condition $\mathsf{int}(A)=\mathsf{int}(B)$ the assertion holds.

Comment: @drhab. Assume $\bar A=\bar B.$ I had just  proved that $\partial A=\partial B\implies $ int ($A$)=int ($B$) when your comment appeared. And I see you  are correct that int($A)=$int($B)\implies \partial A= \partial B.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Yep. It is all in the equality $\partial A=\overline A-\mathsf{int}(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not. Let $A$ be the set of complex nummbers with rational real and imaginary parts and let $B=\mathbb C$. The closures of both the sets are equal to $\mathbb C$. The first one has no interior and the second one is its own interior. So boundary of $A$ is $\mathbb C$ and boundary of $B$ is empty.

If two sets have same closure and same interior then their boundaries are equal.

Comment: Can someone explain why this was downvoted?